# How to resolve missing Glue modules in AWS hosted Apache Zeppelin?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-glue

If you use a EC2 hosted Zeppelin Notebook, it seems to me that it is implied that the AWS Glue libraries are available for use based on this tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/dev-endpoint-tutorial-EC2-notebook.html

Is this assumption incorrect? I have done research on this and it seems that others who have struggled with this had IAM permissions issues.

I have given the Development endpoint these roles (some which may not be necessary, but I am desperate...):

- AWSGlueConsoleSageMakerNotebookFullAccess
- AWSGlueServiceNotebookRole
- AmazonS3FullAccess
- AWSGlueConsoleFullAccess
- AWSGlueServiceRole

The EC2 instance has the following permissions:

- AWSGlueConsoleSageMakerNotebookFullAccess
- AWSCloudFormationFullAccess
- CloudWatchLogsFullAccess
- AmazonAthenaFullAccess
- AWSGlueServiceNotebookRole
- AmazonS3FullAccess
- AWSGlueConsoleFullAccess
- AWSGlueServiceRole

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-4247400967984532782.py", line 349, in <module>
    raise Exception(traceback.format_exc())
Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-4247400967984532782.py", line 337, in <module>
    exec(code)
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
ImportError: No module named awsglue.context
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer for me was to allow network communication between Zeppelin and Glue. You have to explicitly configure this network rule.